# Bind multiple values to a single checkbox and post it to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

**Model.cs**

A campaign can have multiple images, that's why `IEnumerable<int> ImageIdList`.

```
public class Campaign
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
  public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<int> ImageIdList { get; set; }
}
```

**View.cshtml**

I want to download all the images related to a campaign, based on the `ImageIdList`, that's why I need to post all these `ImageIds` when a particular Campaign is checked and download button is clicked.

```
@model Campaign

    @{
      Layout = "....";
      var assets = Model.AssetsInCampaign.ToList();
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("action-method", "controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      <div class="btnSubmit">
        <input type="submit" value="Download Asset(s)" />
      </div>
      @foreach(var i in assets)
      {
        <div class="s_checkcol">
          <input type="checkbox" name="ids" />
          @foreach (var imageId in i.Where(c => c.AssetId == doc.FileDataId).SelectMany(c => c.ImageIdList))
          {
              <input type="hidden" name="ids" value=@(imageId)>
          }
        </div>
      }
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult DownloadFiles(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    // code
}
```

*NOTE: Only a part of code(where I'm facing the problem) is provided here. Its a DB first approach and in no way I can alter that (ORDERS).*

I tried the above, but all of the `ids` are posted to the controller no matter how many checkboxes are selected.

**Question:** How should I bind the `IEnumerable<int> ImageIdList` property to a checkbox in `View.cs` and post the data to `Controller.cs` so that only the `ids` of selected checkboxes are posted?

Comment: Where is checkbox in your view?

Comment: My mistake! Edited. @Roma
Right above `foreach` loop.

Comment: Possible similarity to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221314/how-do-i-bind-checkboxes-to-the-listint-property-of-a-view-model

Comment: You cant bind `IEnumerable<int>` to a checkbox. A checkbox only posts back a single value. Its unclear what you trying to do. And the reason all ID's are posted is because you create a hidden input for each ID. Are you wanting to generate a checkbox for each item in your collection

Comment: I suspect you want something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to bind the list with a single checkbox. So while posting data, all the ids attached to one single checkbox must be posted. There can be a single checkbox or multiple checkboxes and with every checkbox there can be a single or multiple values attached.

Comment: As I stated, a checkbox only posts back a single value. And your code only shows one checkbox so its still unclear what your trying to do or what you expect to post

Comment: Give me some time to edit my question. @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke take a look now. If still in doubt, please ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116084/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-barnes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a nice practice... it will work and Iam working with such a
>   manner (*Iam sure that it will work very well*) but one thing you have to be **very carefull while coding this**, little bit
>   complicated

Iam taking this effort not only for as an answer to this particular question.

Its for all stackoverflow users. Because i never found the below method anyware in stackoverflow.

I get this method by a long search. You people can use this.

It will help you to **avoid for loops** to bind the Checkboxlist

Its the best good for re-usability (**need a single line (max: 20-25 chars to bind a CheckBoxList in Razor**))

**CheckBoxListItem.cs**

> create a New Class CheckBoxListItem //you can use any other names

```
public class CheckBoxListItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**MyModel.cs**

> This is modelclass

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CheckBoxListItem> ChkList { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

> This is controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var model = new MyModel(){
         Id = 0,
         Name = "Your Name",
         ChkList = dbContext.myTable.Select(x => new CheckBoxListItem { ID = x.MyTableFieldID, Display = x.MyTableFieldName, IsChecked = true })
         //If you need only int part, then just avoid to bind data on Display field
     };
     return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel myModel) //Your model object on PostAction
{
    IEnumerable<CheckBoxListItem> ChkList = myModel.ChkList; 
    // Here is your answer, You can see all your check box items (both checked and unchecked) in ChkList, it will shows all your checked items are true and non-checked items are false in IsChecked field 
}
```

> **Here you have to give more patiance**

Goto the Folder **View**>**Shared**>**EditorTemplates** and RightClick Add>View... and Create a new View **with the same name** CheckBoxListItem.cshtml

**CheckBoxListItem.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Models.CheckBoxListItem
<div class="">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
    <div class="">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsChecked, Model.Display, new { @class = "" })
</div>
```

> Create your View

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model @model Project.Models.MyModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "" })
    </div>
</div>

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChkList) //This only one line of code is enough to bind a checkBoxList in future

<input type="submit" value="Create" class="" />
```

You will get all these in your post action