# how to make selectable items using viewbag and input type checkbox, and access checked items in controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, viewbag

Consider we have this three tables

TblProducts

```
+----+----------+-------+
| Id |  Title   | Price |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | product1 |  1000 |
|  2 | product2 |  1000 |
|  3 | product3 |  1000 |
|  4 | product4 |  1000 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

TblOrders

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| Id | UserName | OrderDate |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | user1    | 6/22/2018 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

TblOrderItems

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| Id | OrderId | ProductId |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |         2 |
|  1 |       1 |         4 |
|  1 |       1 |         5 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

I want to show a list of products using checkboxes, so the user can select products

and then Insert order info in TblOrders and selected products Id's in TblOrderItems at the same time.

In the controller, I fetch products list and put it in ViewBag

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ProductList = db.TblProducts.ToList();
            return View();
        }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,UserName,OrderDate")] TblOrder tblOrder,???????????????)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TblOrders.Add(tblOrder);
            foreach (var item in ???????????????)
            {
                db.TblOrderItems.Add(
                    new TblOrderItem()
                    {
                        OrderID=tblOrder.Id,
                        ProductID= item.Id
                    }
                    ); 
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tblOrder);
    }
```

and in view I get ViewBag like below:

```
@model test.Models.TblOrder
@using test.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    List<TblProduct> productLists = ViewBag.ProductList;
}
```

But I don't know how to write part below

```
    @foreach (var item in productLists)
            {
????????????????????????????????????????
                @*<input name="" type="checkbox" />
            <label>@item.Title</label>*@            
}
```

how can bind checkboxes with products and 
how can access select products Ids in the controller?

please consider we have to do this using ViewBag **not** ViewModel, and inputs with type checkboxes **not** MVC checkboxlist helper.

thanks

Comment: Use editor templates. Refer code in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221314/how-do-i-bind-checkboxes-to-the-listint-property-of-a-view-model/12221514#12221514

Comment: Also, why you have to do it using ViewBag, not ViewModel ? Can you tell us the reason ?

Comment: @Shyju, thanks I'm beginner in asp.net mvc, It is for learning and understanding perpuse and And I was very curious,also at my work they use viewbag a lot and Encouraging us to use pure html inputs as much as possible instead of helpers, so If I understand it, we can't do it using viewbag.