# POST Form which has a list of objects as a viewModel property (without ajax)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view model which gets displayed in a cshtml view like this:

```
@model MyViewModel
<form action="...">
  @foreach (var item in this.Model.MyList)
  {
    <input type="checkbox" name="item.Name"/>
  }
</form>
```

Then I have a controller method on the backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMyViewModel(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
...
```

When I inspect the `viewModel` in the controller method while POSTing, it has all null properties. I would expect it to have values in `MyList` and in there, bools for each item in `MyList`.

Is this possible without Ajax? I cannot use ajax here.

What must be done to the form in order to properly return an accurate representation of the viewModel back to the server?

Comment: Which property of `MyViewModel` you want to be populated ? What type is that property ?

Comment: A controller doesn't care if a post came from ajax or from a standard form submit. What does the request body look like from the browser dev tools network trace?

Comment: You can always use editor templates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221314/how-do-i-bind-checkboxes-to-the-listint-property-of-a-view-model/12221514#12221514

Comment: Your checkbox does not even have a `value` attribute (so it will only ever post back "on"` if checked (or nothing is unchecked). And your have given it `name="item.Name"` which would only bind to a model containing a property name `item` which is a complex object. If you want to generate list of checkboxes, refer [Pass List of Checkboxes into View and Pull out IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Comment: Refer also [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand that you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection, and to understand how the `name` attribute relates to your model

Comment: @Shyju - The property is `MyList` which is a list of other viewmodels, all of which have `Name` properties

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `button` to submit the `form` is within the `<form> element` in `HTML`.

When you are POSTing a `List (Array)` of an `Object` from `HTML` to `Controller`, you need to add index of each item in the `List` to the `HTML name property`.

Additionally, the `name property` should also have same name as of the `Property` in the `C#` code.

Your code should look like below to work properly.

```
<form action="...">
   @{ 
var i = 0; 
}
  @foreach (var item in this.Model.MyList)
  { var nameChecked = string.Empty; 
 if(item.Name != null) nameChecked = “checked”;
<input type="checkbox" name="viewModel[i].Name" @nameChecked  />
i++;
  }
</form>
```

> NOTE: This is a basic code sample. You can always enhance to work more efficiently.

Hope this helps!