# ASP.NET MVC static model checkbox values to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to get my checkbox checked values from the view if I set my checkbox values not in the controller but in the model? If it is possible - how to do it?

Model:

```
public static IEnumerable<CheckModels> checkbox() 
{
    List<CheckModels> models = new List<CheckModels>();

    models.Add(new CheckModels { Id = 1, Checked = false, Name = "type1" });
    models.Add(new CheckModels { Id = 2, Checked = false, Name = "type2" });
    models.Add(new CheckModels { Id = 3, Checked = false, Name = "type3" });
    models.Add(new CheckModels { Id = 4, Checked = false, Name = "type4" });
    models.Add(new CheckModels { Id = 5, Checked = false, Name = "type5" });

    return models;
}

public class CheckModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
 @foreach (var items in Models.checkbox())
 {
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => items.Checked)
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => items.Id)
      @Html.DisplayFor(x => items.Name)
  }
```

Controller:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in model.checkbox())
{
    if (item.Checked)
    {
        string name = item.Id;
        sb.Append(item.Id + ",");
    }
}
```

I know I can't get the checked values because it is in static, but how can I get the values from view?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking, or why you are using `static` (although that has nothing to do with it). You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection - you need a `for` loop or an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CheckModels` - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: Here is post with sample code using Editor Templates to solve a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221314/how-do-i-bind-checkboxes-to-the-listint-property-of-a-view-model